# VB6 Outlook 2003 Client Application

Tags: vb6, outlook, freeze

I have a Visual Basic 6 application that uses a timer to poll Outlook 2003 for incoming messages using the **msoutl.olb automation object library**. Lets call the application *MailPoler*.

Based on the messages certain operations gets performed blah blah...

*MailPoler* runs "very smoothly" and I have ensured that the error handler captures and logs any possible error.

The problem I am facing is that after a certain period (1 to 2 days) the *MailPoler* will go into a freeze. Outlook hasn't frozen.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? I have eliminated the possibility of a security issue. Due to the application being able to access Outlook in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose error handling code is implemented on each and every function/sub your app has. If nothing gets logged there then create a separate log that's logging entry/exit points of each routine.

Comment: I already tried it. Its like the application just freezes and I have nothing to go by. I even considered adding logging for a history of all functions called. I am even considering to write a Outlook 2003 Plug-In. If it was up to me I would have already. VB6 Argggg.

Comment: Do you implement events on some outlook classes i.e. `Private WithEvents m_oMySink As OutlookClass`? Try reconnecting these on certian period of time.

Comment: I have implemented a time that connects in intervals of 60 seconds. Is this sufficient? Or would the event be best practice?

Comment: Best practice - no. Desperate hack - yes :-)) Probably the outlook object gets disconnected due to an exception but you never get notified about it so your marshaling proxy becomes loose (dangling). Implementing a "heartbeat" to test your references by calling a single (fast) method on them is also viable. This or reconnecting will probably throw an error but at least you'll know something is wrong with the server application.

Comment: I found that the <code>_NewMail Application</code> event does the trick. Thanks.See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147645.aspx